# Multiple Django template loaders

Tags: python, django, templates, jinja2

I'd like to use Jinja2 with a Django project. I'm using [this](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2063/) template loader from Django Snippets, but I still need to be able to render templates with Django for the admin pages. Whenever I try to use the admin pages, though, I get a TemplateSyntaxError because of the unknown tag "load". Is there a way to make the Jinja template loader defer to Django's built-in system when it can't handle the template?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend using this fork of Coffin when using Jinja and Django templates at the same time: https://github.com/GaretJax/coffin/blame/master/README.rst I implemented this on http://umbel.com/ which uses a combination of Django and Jinja templates.

It has a setting that you can use to disable Jinja's template loader for specific apps:

```
JINJA2_DISABLED_APPS = (
    'admin',
    'auth',
)
```

Hope that helps you out.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad I could help. Jinja2 proved to be a total pain in the a$$ until I found that fork of Coffin.

Comment: 'a$$'.replace('$', 's')